# Analyzing the effects of different scholarships among university students

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, propensity-scores

We have a data set that has data on university students, including their

- socio-demographic characteristics (sex, first language, ethnicity,
  residency etc.),
- GPA and CGPA in each semester (note that some of these fields are
  blank since one may not attend any course in that semester),  the
  number of credit hours (course load) they take (again, some of the
  fields are blank),
- a scale variable measuring how much they preferred the university
  over other universities,
- a scale variable measuring their pre-school performance, and
- information on different scholarships including the semester in which
  a student receives the scholarship(s) (a student can receive multiple
  scholarships at a time, and also the same scholarship multiple
  times). So there is a column for each program. For those who
  received that program, the semester of receiving the program is the
  entry.

We also have the information about the name of subject they were studying (well, some of them also changed their subject after some semester).

Our goal is to evaluate the effect of each scholarship on the basis of CGPA/GPA adjusting for other variables.

This data set is a complex one for the evaluation of scholarships, because

- multiple scholarships at a time can have some joint effect on
  CGPA/GPA,
- students need not attend every semester, and the scholarships are
  optional, not everyone applies for those scholarships. As a result,
  there is actually nothing like "treatment-control",
- there can be some hidden effects, for example, students who applied
  for these kinds of programs were probably more likely to have greater
  determination, initiative, drive, than those who do not,
- some of the subjects are probably harder than the others, and
  consequently may produce consistently less GPA/CGPA,
- every program is needed to be evaluated (in terms of improving the
  GPA/CGPA). But there were some programs where very small proportion
  of students received it.

How would you approach statistically to evaluate each scholarship in this scenario? Is it better to work with GPA or CGPA?

**Edit**

I thought I should provide here how the data may look like after matching:

```
Subject Semester    Type    GPA CourseTaken Scholarship1    Scholarship2    Scholarship3    Covariate1  Covariate2
   1       1      Control   3.5     Yes                                                          2           5
   1       2      Control   3.4     Yes                                                          2           5
   1       3      Control           No                                                           2           5
   2       1      Control           No                                                           3           9
   2       2      Control   3.6     Yes                                                          3           9
   2       3      Control   3.4     Yes                                                          3           9
   3       1      Program   3.7     Yes                         Yes                              1           7
   3       2      Program           No                                                           1           7
   3       3      Program   3.8     Yes                                                          1           7
   4       1      Program   3.25    Yes                                                          3           5
   4       2      Program   3.5     Yes       Yes                               Yes              3           5
   4       3      Program   3.6     Yes       Yes                                                3           5
```

Comment: How many scholarship type you consider and how students you have? I am worried that one might grossly over-fit if the whole design gets finer. Have you tried a basic *merit* vs. *athletic* scholarship effect in balanced sample to get an idea if something seems to be there?

Comment: Well there are a total of 83191 students. The funded programs are (in the bracket the number of students receiving the scholarship is given): equity scholarships (948), job preparedness program (956), student career leadership program (95), student leadership conference (283), skills enhancement programs (110), professional development and community enrichment program (194).

Comment: Are there any students *without* a scholarship of any kind who could act as a kind of control set? I can think of a number of ways of dealing with the "scholarship" factor from individual effects as a function of the specific award, to awards by subject or area of study (e.g., history vs biology or type of program), counts of the number of awards, and so on. Rather than picking GPA vs CPGA, why not build a multivariate regression that uses both metric, kind of like a MANOVA?

Comment: There are so many students without a scholarship. But they are not controls in a real sense, because they probably didn't even apply for the programs. However, we don't have information about who applied and who didn't. We only know information about those students who received a program. We also know the duration of the programs by semester for a particular student. GPA and CGPA measures almost the same thing. CGPA carries forward the effect of previous good or bad results.

Comment: You could probably used a [Mixed Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) approach. I would treat the semester wise GPA as longitudinal data. Your levels are defined by scholarship and have sublevels as the semesters they were received in. See for example a case study: http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/book/Ch4.pdf

Comment: @BlainWaan  I'm think more about treating the students without a scholarship as an information pool with two advantages: 1) together with some external information about population marginals, their presence could facilitate weighting of the sample back to population totals and, 2) they would more properly offset the likelihoods developed in the model.

Comment: @DJohnson I was considering a propensity score matching of to get a control-like cohort of students who didn't receive any program. Do you think introducing an inverse probability weighting can be more appropriate here?

Comment: Gary King, Harvard quantitative political scientist, has a recent paper on using the Mahalanobis distance function in preference to propensity scores for matching. In addition, a few weeks ago he gave an ICM webinar on this topic that pretty thoroughly and clearly documented the motivations for doing so.  Here's the paper   http://gking.harvard.edu/files/gking/files/psnot.pdf?m=1439838506   And here's a link to the ICM webinar   http://www.methods-colloquium.com/#!Gary-King-Why-Propensity-Scores-Should-Not-Be-Used-for-Matching/clv6/55f31b8b0cf20cc524a66366

Comment: @rightskewed Could you please tell me more about how I should use the information of the semesters in which the programs were received. Note that,  the data set has so many blanks-- because GPA was not available for all the semesters, as some students skip semesters. Again, the semester information at which a student receives a program is certainly only available to those who actually received a program.

Comment: What percentage of students have gaps in their records and how long (how many semesters) are those gaps? Wouldn't this argue for preferring CGPA over GPA since CGPA would span the gaps?

Comment: @DJohnson, thank you for the article and the video, how about genetic matching vs PSM? It seems to accomplish what MahalAnobis distance matching achieves but is a much more efficient way? Thank you

Comment: @DJohnson Well, in fact many! We have 83191 students. Dropping semester is quite common among students. I have added a possible look of the data.

Comment: @BlainWaan I'm sure that's true and, in all likelihood, is a financially motivated decision as students struggle to balance school, jobs, families and life. How many universities are represented in your data and are you able to distinguish between public (e.g., state schools) vs private?

Comment: @forecaster  *Genetic mapping* is new to me but what King presents as a compelling reason for preferring Mahalanobis distance over PSM is the precision of the resulting matches (watch the webinar where this is made explicit). If GM delivers similar levels of precision with a computationally more efficient algorithm, then *yes* use GM, no question. Otherwise, trading less precision for more efficiency seems unproductive.

Comment: @DJohnson Actually this is a data set from only one university.